# How to serialize and deserialize objects of abstract class or interface in java?

Tags: json, serialization, interface, deserialization, abstract-class

I'm new to the world of json. I referred few questions that is asked on stackoverflow on this. I tried out as said in http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization, but didn't get working. I'm using mongoDB.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property= "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = UserImpl.class, name = "userData")})
public abstract class User {
    public abstract long getId();
    public abstract void setId(long id);
    public abstract String getFirstName();
    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);
}

@JsonTypeName("userData")
public class UserImpl extends User {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
// Constructor
//Getter and setter
}
```

I've added below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm just trying to add data into the user table. I'm getting

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.example.model.User using constructor public com.example.model.User() with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251)
....
```

PLease help as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing wrong with the code. I had some data in the User table before adding the annotations. Had to remove all the data and then try. Worked!!!